# md5 query nonfunctional in php

Tags: php

Why the following query doesn't work?
I'm working with md5 and it doesn't do anything.

```
 $query = "select email from user where email='".$email."' and password='".md5('$password')."'";
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't use quotes around `$password`. It's unneeded, and single quotes means that it will pass the phrase `$password`, not the value.

Comment: `md5` is not a good way to encrypt a password given that `password_hash` is exactly as simple to use and much more secure.

Comment: ***You really shouldn't use [MD5 password hashes](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure)*** and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. Make sure  you [don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the quotes in md5 encryption

```
md5('$password') to md5($password)

$query = "select email from user where email='".$email."' and password='".md5($password)."'";
```

Comment: I understand that you're trying to help the OP, but please do not reinforce the habit of using MD5 hashes for passwords.